# How can I set maxChunkSize for MMapDirectoryFactory in solr?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, mmap

I was reading through the MMapDirectoryFactory and how to set it as DirectoryFactory to use for indexes in my core's solrconfig.xml.

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
                  class="solr.MMapDirectoryFactory">
  <bool name="preload">true</bool>
</directoryFactory>
```

I am not able to understand nor able to find any example about how to set the maxChunkSize.

references:

- https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/datadir-and-directoryfactory-in-solrconfig.html-
- https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/core/MMapDirectoryFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
                      class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.MMapDirectoryFactory}">
        <int name="maxChunkSize">1073741824</int>
        <bool name="preload">true</bool>
    </directoryFactory>
```

I hope you are looking for this.

Please note there is a validation in place for chunk size.

```
  public MMapDirectory(Path path, LockFactory lockFactory, int maxChunkSize) throws IOException {
    ...
    this.chunkSizePower = 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(maxChunkSize);
    assert this.chunkSizePower >= 0 && this.chunkSizePower <= 30;
  }
```

However, that said, you ideally would not be required to modify this param for modern production systems (as they would usually be 64-bit already) per the java doc.

> Create a new MMapDirectory for the named location, specifying the maximum chunk size used for memory mapping. The directory is created at the named location if it does not yet exist.
> Especially on 32 bit platform, the address space can be very fragmented, so large index files cannot be mapped. Using a lower chunk size makes the directory implementation a little bit slower (as the correct chunk may be resolved on lots of seeks) but the chance is higher that mmap does not fail. **On 64 bit Java platforms, this parameter should always be 1 << 30, as the address space is big enough.**